# woocommerce : shipping details not displaying at thank you page when checking out from cart page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using payapal-for-woocommerce plugin for express checkout in my shopping site.

when I checkouts from woocommerce checkout page. I have shipping and billing details on my order-received page that is fine. but when I checkout from cart page on order-received page it displays only Billing details.

I go through woocommerce\templates\order\order-details-customer.php file on line no line no 55

```
 if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() ) :
```

$order->needs_shipping_address()  this function always shows me null . so I can see,  that is why shipping details is not showing.

If I want to pass $order->needs_shipping_address() = 'True' or 'Free_shipping' in shipping method by default how can i do it using hook or filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually When you submit your request using EC PayMent then you will not store the shipping fields in order item table. Please make sure on this. Is it storing or not? if Not storing "Free shipping" then needs_shipping_address() function return false value.

Please review it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Chirag its resolved by inserting record into woocommerce_order_items table as you suggested.